# Submit GET form and another POST form with one button

Tags: javascript, php, forms, request

I'm trying to submit a POST and a GET form with one submit button. I tried using the following php code:

```
echo "<html>\n<head>\n<title>Params</title>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "function submitForms(){
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    document.getElementById('form2').submit();
}";
echo "</script>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<form action='' method='get' id='form1'>";
echo "<label>First Name </label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='first'><br/>";
echo "<label>Last Name </label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='last'><br/>";
echo "<label>Age </label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='age'><br/>";
echo "<label>Telephone </label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='phone'><br />";
echo "</form>";
echo "<form action='' method='post' id='form2'>";
echo "<label>Username </label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='username'>";
echo "<label>Password </label>";
echo "<input type='password' name='password'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Send' onclick='submitForms();'>";
echo "</body></html>";
```

What I get is only the POST params, while the GET request is not loading at all.
How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could remove the echo and the quotation marks then made it run as a simple html.

Comment: As soon as you call `.submit()`, the page reloads and the rest of the script stops. The only way to do multiple submits is with AJAX.

Comment: and the reason why you need both? why not use one?

Comment: The conflict is probably in the refresh of the page which happens when submitting.

Comment: I thought so , thank you, it's a university assignment where I need to use both GET and POST...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should take only one form all fields in that and after getting all input data after submit you can do whatever you want to do..

The way you are doing this is not possible reason being when form is submitted control goes to server to handle http request. hence only one form can be submit at a time. You can't submit two forms at once.. try changing order of form submit and other form will start submitting..

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX (jQuery). Something like this should do the trick:

```
//Onclick for any button you wish to submit the forms
$('#form2 input[name="submit"]').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var formOne = $("#form1"),
        formTwo = $("#form2");

    //Post first form
    $.post( formOne.attr('action') , formOne.serialize(), function() {
        alert('Form one posted!');
    });

    //Post second form
    $.post( formTwo.attr('action') , formTwo.serialize(), function() {
        alert('Form two posted!');
    });
});
```

Not tested yet, but this should work. More information for the `$.post` method can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).